# Falling left and right inconsistencies in pygame platformer

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a 2D Minecraft like game. I found this bug that I don't know how to fix (the details are below), I kinda like things to be perfect so I can't continue with this bug present.

First of all here is the code:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from random import *
from math import *
import json
import os
import opensimplex

FPS = 60
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 600, 300
SCR_DIM = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
GRAVITY = 0.25
SLIDE = 0.15
TERMINAL_VEL = 12
BLOCK_SIZE = 32
CHUNK_SIZE = 8
SEED = randint(-2147483648, 2147483647)

def loading():
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 60)
    textsurface = font.render('Generating World...', True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(textsurface, (25, 100))
    display.blit(pygame.transform.scale(screen, (WIDTH*2, HEIGHT*2)), (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH*2, HEIGHT*2), HWSURFACE | DOUBLEBUF)
pygame.display.set_caption("2D Minecraft")
screen = pygame.Surface(SCR_DIM)
loading()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
mixer = pygame.mixer.init()
vec = pygame.math.Vector2
noise = opensimplex.OpenSimplex(seed=SEED)
seed(SEED)

font12 = pygame.font.SysFont("consolas", 12)

block_textures = {}
for img in os.listdir("res/textures/blocks/"):
    block_textures[img[:-4]] = pygame.image.load("res/textures/blocks/"+img).convert_alpha()
for image in block_textures:
    block_textures[image] = pygame.transform.scale(block_textures[image], (BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE))
block_data = {}
for j in os.listdir("res/block_data/"):
    block_data[j[:-5]] = json.loads(open("res/block_data/"+j, "r").read())

player_head_img = pygame.image.load("res/textures/player/head.png").convert_alpha()
player_body_img = pygame.image.load("res/textures/player/body.png").convert_alpha()
player_arm_img = pygame.image.load("res/textures/player/arm.png").convert_alpha()
player_leg_img = pygame.image.load("res/textures/player/leg.png").convert_alpha()
head_size = vec(player_head_img.get_width()*2, player_head_img.get_height()*2)
body_size = vec(player_body_img.get_width()*2, player_body_img.get_height()*2)
arm_size = vec(player_arm_img.get_width()*2, player_arm_img.get_height()*2)
leg_size = vec(player_leg_img.get_width()*2, player_leg_img.get_height()*2)
player_head = pygame.Surface(head_size, SRCALPHA)
player_body = pygame.Surface(body_size, SRCALPHA)
player_arm = pygame.Surface(arm_size, SRCALPHA)
player_leg = pygame.Surface(leg_size, SRCALPHA)
player_head.blit(player_head_img, (head_size/4))
player_body.blit(player_body_img, (body_size/4))
player_arm.blit(player_arm_img, (arm_size/2+vec(-2, -2)))
player_leg.blit(player_leg_img, (leg_size/2+vec(-2, 0)))

def intv(vector):
    return vec(int(vector.x), int(vector.y))

def inttup(tup):
    return (int(tup[0]), int(tup[1]))

def text(text, color=(0, 0, 0)):
    return font12.render(text, True, color)

def block_collide(ax, ay, width, height, b):
    a_rect = pygame.Rect(ax-camera.offset.x, ay-camera.offset.y, width, height)
    b_rect = pygame.Rect(b.pos.x-camera.offset.x, b.pos.y-camera.offset.y, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE)
    if a_rect.colliderect(b_rect):
        return True
    return False

def remove_block(pos):
    pos = inttup(pos)
    chunk = (pos[0] // CHUNK_SIZE, pos[1] // CHUNK_SIZE)
    try:
        del blocks[pos]
        del chunks[chunk].block_data[pos]
    except:
        pass

def set_block(pos, name):
    pos = inttup(pos)
    chunk = (pos[0] // CHUNK_SIZE, pos[1] // CHUNK_SIZE)
    try:
        blocks[pos] = Block(chunks[chunk], pos, name)
        chunks[chunk].block_data[pos] = name
    except:
        pass

def is_occupied(pos):
    pos = inttup(pos)
    try: blocks[pos]
    except:
        if pygame.Rect(vec(pos)*BLOCK_SIZE, (BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE)).colliderect(pygame.Rect(player.pos, player.size)):
            return True
        return False
    else:
        try: blocks[pos].data["replaceable"]
        except: return True
        else: return False
    return True

def is_supported(pos, data, neighbors):
    if data["support"]:
        supports = data["support"]
        for support in supports:
            try: blocks[neighbors[support]]
            except: return False
            else:
                if blocks[neighbors[support]].name == supports[support]:
                    return True
        return False
    return True

def is_placable(pos, data, neighbors):
    if not is_occupied(pos) and is_supported(pos, data, neighbors):
        return True
    return False

class Camera(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.actual_offset = self.master.size / 2
        self.offset = intv(self.actual_offset)
        self.actual_offset = self.master.pos - self.offset - vec(SCR_DIM) / 2 + self.master.size / 2

    def update(self):
        tick_offset = self.master.pos - self.offset - vec(SCR_DIM) / 2 + self.master.size / 2
        if -1 < tick_offset.x < 1:
            tick_offset.x = 0
        if -1 < tick_offset.y < 1:
            tick_offset.y = 0
        self.actual_offset += tick_offset / 10
        self.offset = intv(self.actual_offset)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((0, 0))
        self.size = vec(0.225*BLOCK_SIZE, 1.8*BLOCK_SIZE)
        self.width, self.height = self.size.x, self.size.y
        self.start_pos = vec(0, 3) * BLOCK_SIZE
        self.pos = vec(self.start_pos)
        self.coords = self.pos // BLOCK_SIZE
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.max_speed = 2.6
        self.jumping_max_speed = 3.2
        self.rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0, 0.225*BLOCK_SIZE, 1.8*BLOCK_SIZE))
        self.bottom_bar = pygame.Rect((self.rect.x+1, self.rect.bottom), (self.width-2, 1))
        self.on_ground = False
        self.holding = "grass_block"

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_a]:
            if self.vel.x > -self.max_speed:
                self.vel.x -= SLIDE
        elif self.vel.x < 0:
            self.vel.x += SLIDE
        if keys[K_d]:
            if self.vel.x < self.max_speed:
                self.vel.x += SLIDE
        elif self.vel.x > 0:
            self.vel.x -= SLIDE
        if keys[K_w] and self.on_ground:
            self.vel.y = -4.6
            self.vel.x *= 1.1
            if self.vel.x > self.jumping_max_speed:
                self.vel.x = self.jumping_max_speed
            elif self.vel.x < -self.jumping_max_speed:
                self.vel.x = -self.jumping_max_speed
        if -SLIDE < self.vel.x < SLIDE:
            self.vel.x = 0

        self.vel.y += GRAVITY
        if self.vel.y > TERMINAL_VEL:
            self.vel.y = TERMINAL_VEL
        self.move()
        self.bottom_bar = pygame.Rect((self.rect.left+1, self.rect.bottom), (self.width-2, 1))
        for block in blocks:
            if self.bottom_bar.colliderect(blocks[block].rect):
                self.on_ground = True
                break
        else:
            self.on_ground = False
        self.coords = self.pos // BLOCK_SIZE
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos - camera.offset

    def draw(self, screen):
        # screen.blit(self.image, self.rect.topleft)
        pass

    def move(self):
        coords = self.pos // BLOCK_SIZE
        for y in range(4):
            for x in range(3):
                try:
                    block = blocks[(int(coords.x-1+x), int(coords.y-1+y))]
                except:
                    pass
                else:
                    if block.data["collision_box"] == "full":
                        if self.vel.y < 0:
                            if block_collide(self.pos.x, self.pos.y+self.vel.y, self.width, self.height, block):
                                self.pos.y = (block.pos.y + BLOCK_SIZE)
                                self.vel.y = 0
                        elif self.vel.y >= 0:
                            if block_collide(self.pos.x, ceil(self.pos.y+self.vel.y), self.width, self.height, block):
                                self.pos.y = ceil(block.pos.y - self.height)
                                self.vel.y = 0
                        if self.vel.x < 0:
                            if block_collide(self.pos.x+self.vel.x, self.pos.y, self.width, self.height, block):
                                self.pos.x = (block.pos.x + BLOCK_SIZE)
                                self.vel.x = 0
                        elif self.vel.x >= 0:
                            if block_collide(ceil(self.pos.x+self.vel.x), self.pos.y, self.width, self.height, block):
                                self.pos.x = ceil(block.pos.x - self.width)
                                self.vel.x = 0
        self.pos += self.vel

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, chunk, pos, name):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        blocks[tuple(pos)] = self
        self.name = name
        self.data = block_data[self.name]
        self.chunk = chunk
        self.coords = vec(pos)
        self.pos = self.coords * BLOCK_SIZE
        self.neighbors = {
            "up": inttup((self.coords.x, self.coords.y-1)), 
            "down": inttup((self.coords.x, self.coords.y+1)), 
            "left": inttup((self.coords.x-1, self.coords.y)), 
            "right": inttup((self.coords.x+1, self.coords.y))
        }
        self.image = block_textures[self.name]
        if self.data["collision_box"] == "full":
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.pos, (BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE))
        elif self.data["collision_box"] == "none":
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.pos, (0, 0))

    def update(self):
        if not is_supported(self.pos, self.data, self.neighbors):
            remove_blocks.append(self.coords)
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos - camera.offset

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect.topleft)

class Chunk(object):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.pos = pos
        self.block_data = generate_chunk(pos[0], pos[1])
        for block in self.block_data:
            blocks[block] = Block(self, block, self.block_data[block])

    def render(self):
        if self.pos in rendered_chunks:
            for block in self.block_data:
                try: blocks[block]
                except:
                    blocks[block] = Block(self, block, self.block_data[block])
                blocks[block].update()
                blocks[block].draw(screen)

    def debug(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 0), (self.pos[0]*CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE-camera.offset[0], self.pos[1]*CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE-camera.offset[1], CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE, CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE), width=1)

def generate_chunk(x, y):
    chunk_data = {}
    for y_pos in range(CHUNK_SIZE):
        for x_pos in range(CHUNK_SIZE):
            target = (x * CHUNK_SIZE + x_pos, y * CHUNK_SIZE + y_pos)
            block_name = ""
            height = int(noise.noise2d(target[0]*0.1, 0)*5)
            if target[1] == 5-height:
                block_name = "grass_block"
            elif 5-height < target[1] < 10-height:
                block_name = "dirt"
            elif target[1] >= 10-height:
                block_name = "stone"
            elif target[1] == 4-height:
                if randint(0, 2) == 0:
                    block_name = "grass"
            if block_name != "":
                chunk_data[target] = block_name
    return chunk_data

blocks = {}
chunks = {}
player = Player()
camera = Camera(player)

remove_blocks = []

def draw():
    screen.fill((135, 206, 250))
    for chunk in rendered_chunks:
        chunks[chunk].render()
    player.draw(screen)
    screen.blit(text(f"Holding: {player.holding}", color=(255, 255, 255)), (0, HEIGHT-12))
    if debug:
        for chunk in rendered_chunks:
            chunks[chunk].debug()
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), player.rect, width=1)
        screen.blit(text(f"Seed: {SEED}"), (0, 0))
        screen.blit(text(f"Velocity: {(round(player.vel.x, 3), round(player.vel.y, 3))}"), (0, 12))
        screen.blit(text(f"Position: {inttup(player.coords)}"), (0, 24))
        screen.blit(text(f"Camera offset: {inttup(player.pos-camera.offset-vec(SCR_DIM)/2+player.size/2)}"), (0, 36))
        mpos = vec(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
        block_pos = (player.pos+(mpos/2-player.rect.topleft))//BLOCK_SIZE
        screen.blit(text(f"Chunk: {inttup(player.coords//CHUNK_SIZE)}"), (0, 48))
        screen.blit(text(f"Chunks loaded: {len(chunks)}"), (0, 60))
        screen.blit(text(f"Rendered blocks: {len(blocks)}"), (0, 72))
        try:
            screen.blit(text(f"{blocks[inttup(block_pos)].name.replace('_', ' ')}", color=(255, 255, 255)), (mpos[0]/2, mpos[1]/2-12))
        except:
            pass
    display.blit(pygame.transform.scale(screen, (WIDTH*2, HEIGHT*2)), (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

running = True
debug = True

while running:
    dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 16
    pygame.display.set_caption(f"2D Minecraft | FPS: {int(clock.get_fps())}")

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mpos = vec(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
            block_pos = (player.pos+(mpos/2-player.rect.topleft))//BLOCK_SIZE
            if event.button == 1:
                remove_block(block_pos)
            if event.button == 3:
                if not is_occupied(block_pos):
                    set_block(block_pos, player.holding)
                    blocks[inttup(block_pos)].update()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_1:
                player.holding = "grass_block"
            elif event.key == K_2:
                player.holding = "dirt"
            elif event.key == K_3:
                player.holding = "stone"
            elif event.key == K_4:
                player.holding = "grass"
            if event.key == K_F5:
                debug = not debug

    rendered_chunks = []
    for y in range(int(HEIGHT/(CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE)+2)):
        for x in range(int(WIDTH/(CHUNK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE)+2)):
            chunk = (
                x - 1 + int(round(camera.offset.x / (CHUNK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE))), 
                y - 1 + int(round(camera.offset.y / (CHUNK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE)))
            )
            rendered_chunks.append(chunk)
            if chunk not in chunks:
                chunks[chunk] = Chunk(chunk)
    unrendered_chunks = []
    for chunk in chunks:
        if chunk not in rendered_chunks:
            unrendered_chunks.append(chunk)
    for chunk in unrendered_chunks:
        for block in chunks[chunk].block_data:
            if block in blocks:
                blocks[block].kill()
                del blocks[block]
    for block in remove_blocks:
        remove_block(block)
    remove_blocks = []

    camera.update()
    player.update()
    draw()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

When I make a setup like [image: 1]

and stand on top of the center block, and jump to the right side, I should fall into the 2 blocks tall gap, but instead, I slide pass the gap and fall down and end up like this [image: 3]

It used to happen on both sides but I seemed to have fixed the left side by swapping the y-axis collision detection and the x-axis

```py
if self.vel.y < 0:
    if block_collide(self.pos.x, self.pos.y+self.vel.y, self.width, self.height, block):
        self.pos.y = (block.pos.y + BLOCK_SIZE)
        self.vel.y = 0
elif self.vel.y >= 0:
    if block_collide(self.pos.x, ceil(self.pos.y+self.vel.y), self.width, self.height, block):
        self.pos.y = ceil(block.pos.y - self.height)
        self.vel.y = 0
if self.vel.x < 0:
    if block_collide(self.pos.x+self.vel.x, self.pos.y, self.width, self.height, block):
        self.pos.x = (block.pos.x + BLOCK_SIZE)
        self.vel.x = 0
elif self.vel.x >= 0:
    if block_collide(ceil(self.pos.x+self.vel.x), self.pos.y, self.width, self.height, block):
        self.pos.x = ceil(block.pos.x - self.width)
        self.vel.x = 0
```

But I couldn't figure out how to prevent it from happening on the right side too.

Comment: Could you produce a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Many users seem to avoid long posts, so you could compact it and write the shortest code needed to help you to fix the problem. That way this post would be more readable and more understandable.

Comment: ohhhh thank you so much for the suggestion, I will do that :)

Comment: Maybe it's due to this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/39324985/6486738

Comment: Also, just looking at the images (haven't looked at the code) it seems like the player is not positioned at the center of the block. Make sure it's not the case that the player is simply closer to the left than the right.

Comment: Counted the pixels; the player is 6 pixels in from the left side and 7 pixels in from the right side. If you want the physics to work properly, then you must allow subpixel positioning, which usually is to store the position in floats instead of ints. Note that `pygame.Rect` uses ints and can't be used for positioning in this case.

Comment: Have an example of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42093505/6486738). It contains a bit of math, but you can ignore it if you're not comfortable with vectors and just look at how to handle the position and rect separately.

Comment: I have a pos vector to store the position of the player in pixels, with floating point. It is being combined with the camera offset when updating the rect, and then it is drawn to the screen.

Comment: Is it possible to upload a gif?

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 possible problems.

Either the player hits the block above on the left. In this case `self.vel.x` is set 0 a nd the player falls down. This is just an issue with your game map but not with your code.

Or you hit the block in the top left corner:

[image]

The collision detection is executed and a collision along the x and y axes is detected. The detection along the y-axis moves the player to the top of the block. The collision along the x-axis moves the player to the left of the block:

[image]

No collision is detected in the next frame and the player falls to the ground.

---

One way to solve the problem is to completely split the collision detection into two separate passes for the y-axis and x-axis:

- detect collisions along y axis
- move y
- detect collisions along x axis
- move x

This causes the player to move to the top of the block and no collision is detected at all along the x-axis::

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and answering, but I just replaced my move function and it still doesn't work, it made no difference

Comment: I see your logic and I understand how it would solve the problem, but implementing the code doesn't work